# DraftSight activation does not work

Tags: cad

Every time I start DraftSight (14.04 LTS) I am asked to activate the product. I have filled in the required questionnaire several times over but the product activation is not triggered. In a couple of days the trial period expiries so I would be glad if I could get some help solving this issue before that.

My installed version is

```
apt-cache policy draftsight
>> draftsight:
>>  Installé : 2015.2.0.2052
>>  Candidat : 2015.2.0.2052
>> Table de version :
>> *** 2015.2.0.2052 0
>>        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to circumvent this problem by both removing DraftSight and deleting all local files and folders associated with DraftSight:

```
rm -Rv ~/.config/DraftSight
rm -Rv ~/.config/Dassault Systemes
```

thereafter re-installing DraftSight. This provokes the activation process to re-initiate. Thereafter the activation process worked just fine when filling in the required formulae.

Comment: Is this correct? The second line removes `~/.config/Dassault` and `Systemes` (two names, not one with space, the second one from the current directory!)